# Magento indexes are broken, advanced search can't find all products

Tags: magento

We have around 20000 products in Magento catalog, most of which are updated by daily from different imports. For some reason Magento suddenly isn't finding all the products it should. For example finding using advanced search and using Brand field with "Brand #1" only 41 products are found though there are over 500 of those.

If I open missing products through admin I see that the correct brand is selected. This can be fixed by changing it to something else, then saving, then changing it back and saving. Product is instantly found through Advanced search.

I've tried reindexing multiple times and from command line, even tried truncating index_* tables and rebuilding the indexes, but still not working.

Does someone has some idea what tables should I get fixed and how in order to get all the products working?

I even tried this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');  

foreach ($collection as $_product) {
   echo $_product->getName().":  ";
   echo $_product->getAttributeText('brand')."\n";
}
```

It only displays correct brand for the products found in advanced search, though others have that selected in admin correctly.